# Why would a toilet tank keep refilling even after replacing the flap?

Tags: leak, toilet, leaking

Long story short, my parent's toilet tank was leaking every so often.  I drew a line on the inside of the toilet tank to see if water was leaking out of the tank.  I also turned off the water so it would be easier to see any water level change.

In any case, I saw the level drop and replaced the flapper.  I THINK I installed it correctly as I followed the directions on the package and when I checked again, it wasn't leaking water (followed my above steps, etc. etc.).

Now like 3 months later, they again say that same toilet tank is leaking water.  I haven't had a chance to look at it a second time but I'm just wondering what else could be wrong to make the tank leak water again?  Did I install something wrong?  What might cause an even slower leak that takes longer than 10 minutes to show up?

Comment: In the future rather than turning off the water and waiting for the level to drop, you might consider trying food dye in the tank.  


Why do they think it is leaking again?   Are they hearing it running sometimes?   How often?  Or is it doing something else?  Does jiggling the handle help stop it?

Comment: @BowlOfRed, yeah, they say they hear it running from time to time.  I'll have to check it out for myself the next time I visit.

Answer (score 2):

1. You could have installed a defective flap.
2. The area of the toilet that makes contact with the flapper could be damaged, eroded, or have something there (calcification, etc.) that is keeping it from making a seal. If that's the case, just a bit of sandpaper around the hole where the flap lands should clear whatever is there.
3. The chain fastener to the flush lever sometimes gets caught and doesn't let the flapper all the way back down. (from comments)

In any case, toilets are surprisingly cheap. For <$100 you can buy a new one. It might be worth it for you to avoid the callback.

Comment: 3.  The chain fastener to the flush lever sometimes gets caught and doesn't let the flapper all the way back down.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question and not saying I installed it wrong :)   I'll try another brand of flap to check #1 and the chain for #3.  Not sure if I'm experienced enough for #2 unless it's super obvious but thanks for the extra advice/areas to check.

Comment: @Classified Just a bit of sandpaper around the hole where the flap lands. That should do it.